# Nested UIScrollView With UIImageview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

Before describing my problem a very basic question,is there a way can we return `UIScrollView` object from this method

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Now my problem is, I have a parent `scrollview` with multiple child `scrollview` inside it(all horizontal and paging enabled).

Each child `scrollview` has an `ImageView`. I am getting `zoomScale` factor from server and based on the `image`, I have to zoom it, The problem is when I try to zoom a child `scrollView` which has `image` inside it,it only zooms the last child `scrollview`.

So I think, I need to find out a way where we can return a `scrollview` form the above written delegate.

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

---

THis is UIView Class and i added scrollView and image on this and returned imageView For scrollView Delegate

**SAMPLE CODE**:

```
     - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame image:(UIImage *)image
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];      
        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        self.imageView.tag = VIEW_FOR_ZOOM_TAG;
        self.imageView.frame=frame;//CGRectMake(8,8 ,305, 400);
        [self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];


        self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.4f;
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0f;
        self.scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0f;
        self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.bounds.size;
        self.scrollView.delegate = self;
        self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        [self.scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
        [self addSubview:self.scrollView];

        NSLog(@"ScrollViewPostion %f",self.scrollView.frame.origin.x);
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma -mark
#pragma -mark ScrollViewDelegates
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return [scrollView viewWithTag:VIEW_FOR_ZOOM_TAG];
}
```

And in my main viewController class i am doing this but its not adding all the images properly in the scrollview

```
 NSLog(@"Inner scrollFrame and content size %f %f",innerScrollFrame.origin.x,mainScrollView.contentSize.width);
    JoinSeeSubView *subView=[[JoinSeeSubView alloc] initWithFrame:innerScrollFrame image:img];
    [self.mainScrollView addSubview:subView];


        if (i < [self.allUrlArray count]-1) {
            innerScrollFrame.origin.x += innerScrollFrame.size.width;
    }
    i++;
    mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(innerScrollFrame.origin.x + innerScrollFrame.size.width, mainScrollView.bounds.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the above approach didn't help someone really in need,I solved this problem in a different way,but not sure if it is correct way to do this.

So instead of creating a new class which extends UIView,I create and array and store all the objects of inner scrollview in that array.So my code look something like

```
       UIScrollView *pageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:innerScrollFrame];
        pageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.4f;
        pageScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0f;
        pageScrollView.zoomScale = 1.0f;
        pageScrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        pageScrollView.delegate = self;
        [pageScrollView addSubview:self.imageview];
        [mainScrollView addSubview:pageScrollView];
        [self.pageScrollViewObjArray addObject:pageScrollView];
```

And whenever i need to access a particular imageview contained inside scrollview i do this :-

```
UIScrollView *sv=(UIScrollView*)[self.pageScrollViewObjArray objectAtIndex:swipeCounter];
sv.zoomScale=1.0f;
```

But as i said earlier i don't know how efficient this code is,but its been more than a month the app is on store and being tested properly ,yet no issue because of this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, but you are looping through several images and re-writing the `imageView` and `pageScrollView` properties, so after the last one is added, that's where your pointer will be pointing, and that's why it only zooms your last image.

The best way to go, is to create a `UIView` subclass that handles each image and it's parent scroll view, and simply add that class to your main `UIScrollView`

If you don't want to do that, you will have to find another way to access each separate `UIScrollView`, possibly using tags, but that's not recommended

---

**EDIT - SOME BASE CODE**:

```
@interface A : UIView {
    UIScrollView *scrollView
    UIImage View *imageView;

}
// initialization method that gets the image and the CGRect
@end
@implementation A
// implement initialization that loads the UIImage into the imageView, and set scrollView.delegate = self
// implement scroll view delegate method viewForZooming and return the imageView
@end
```

and then, on whatever class you are working with right now:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imagesCount; i++) {
    UIImage *image = ...; // image i
    CGRect rect = ...; // find rect
    A *subview = [[A alloc] initWithFrame:rect image:image]
    [self.mainScroll addSubview:subview];
}
```

Comment: Do you mean i should add the child scrollview on a view and add that view on main scrollview??

Comment: And for your other solution that you said to access each sepearate UIScrollView with tag,but in that case the problem is how would i get the object of each scrollview.?

Comment: No, I mean create a subclass that handles the image and it's scroll view, so that your main view's only responsibility is to add the images and control the main scroll view, and leave the image zooming and stuff for each of this new class you need to create to handle on their own

Comment: Can you please write a sample for this.

Comment: Hi,
I have updated my code can you please verify it.I followed the same approach suggested by you but its not creating the imaged properly in scrollview.